# Access CUDA runtime with python

Tags: python, cuda

I found following code to access the CUDA runtime through python, or rather, load the libraries to do so:

```
libnames = ("libcuda.so", "libcuda.dylib", "cuda.dll")
for libname in libnames:
    try:
        cuda = ctypes.CDLL(libname)
    except OSError:
        continue
    else:
        break
else:
    return (0, 0, 0.0, "Could not load CUDA library")
```

This code works perfectly fine for Linux, and I was told also for Mac, but for Windows it won't open a CUDA.dll, saying it cannot find it. My filesystem does not contain a `CUDA.DLL`, instead I have `cudart64_110.dll`, `cufft64_10.dll`, and others that came with the CUDA SDK (I have 11.0, 11.1 and 11.4 installed right now). In the lib folder, there is a cuda.lib.

Can I do it somehow with Windows, or do I have to use `pyculib`

Comment: The library you are referring to as "runtime" isn't. It's the Cuda driver API library, and it is part of the NVIDIA driver distribution, not the toolkit.

Comment: I don't have a windows machine handy, but last time I looked at a GPU driver install in windows, the relevant file was `nvcuda.dll` not `cuda.dll`, and it is/was located in `C:\Windows\System32` (for a proper driver install).  So if you don't have any file like that, it means that either 1. You don't have a CUDA capable GPU  2. You have a CUDA capable GPU but don't have a proper driver install to enable CUDA. A driver fetched from e.g. windows update may not have this file installed, for example.  If you have a CUDA capable GPU, the suggestion is install the latest driver from a NVIDIA source.

Comment: Yeah, that worked. Using nvcuda.dll was the issue, the code I used was wrong. That would be an acceptable answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in comments, the CUDA driver API is called `nvcuda.dll` on Windows systems. The toolkit ships with a stub library for linking purposes and the actual library comes with the NVIDIA driver package.

> instead I have cudart64_110.dll, cufft64_10.dll

Those two libraries are actually the CUDA runtime API library. This is a different library with a different set of APIs from the driver API.